# Support background location updates in iOS6 to 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager, background-task

Is it possible to support background location updates from iOS6.0 all the way to the new iOS9?

Also, is is possible to keep the app updating the location in background even when the app is closed or when the device is locked?

Can you please give me some documentation about how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update**

I've downloaded a sample project from [here](https://github.com/voyage11/GettingLocationWhenSuspended) but for some reason it's not updating location in background, even when using simulated location and moving more than 500m. So i've changed this 2 methods:

```
- (void)startMonitoringLocation {
    if (_anotherLocationManager)
        [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    self.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
    _anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    _anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)restartMonitoringLocation {
    [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

And instead of using `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, I'm now using `stopUpdatingLocation` and `startUpdatingLocation`. The problem is that now when I'm going to background, it's starting to fetch location and never stops. Why?

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible , but why do you need to use the IOS 6 , i have no idea , by the way of you want to send location update at background this code will help you through this

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{

    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The app needs to register the background mode for location updates.

See the [Background Execution chapter in the App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1)